# How to define a group policy that to allow submitters to edit only yours items submitted in Dspace?

Tags: dspace

I'm trying to define a group policy that allows the user to edit just their own material. But I have not found a way to set the user to edit only their items. I can only give permission to edit but for all items in the collection.

In summary I wanted to assign the user to edit their own items without editing the items of the other users of the same collection. Is it possible on the DSpace?

Comment: If you do not get a good response here, try the DSpace tech mailing list.  Are your items in a workflow, or do they need to be perpetually editable by author?

Comment: The intent is for the user to manage their own content. Without intervention from the administrator.

Comment: @BrendowAdriel, did you manage to accomplish this? It would be nice if you could post your steps as the answer to your question. I am also interested in this.

Comment: Hello @euler, So. I added the submitter user, in the collection admin group. But I had to implement some restrictions on item metadata editing page and collection editing. It was not possible to do this without programming.

Comment: I asked because this question was linked from this DSpace-Tech Mailing list post: [https://groups.google.com/g/dspace-tech/c/2vvjIUFHsnI/m/1sNNiu3rBgAJ] Well, if doing this is not trivial and requires a lot of coding, I would just have to tell submitters to contact their collection administrator to do the editing in behalf of them.

Comment: It's not a lot of coding, but it's good to understand the rules of dspace as well so you don't break other functionality. Basically,
  is by limiting the visibility of the metadata edit form to only the desired fields. The version I used was dspace 5.6.

You can found it here:
https://wiki.lyrasis.org/display/DSPACE/Developer+Guidelines+and+Tools

Comment: Would you mind sharing your steps as an answer? This could be very helpful for administrators and other members such as metadata editors since it will lessen a lot of burden from them if the submitters can actually edit their own submission.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to give to the submitter the ADMIN permission on the ITEM after than the item has been archived. This should enable him to edit the item using the administrative edit. He will be also able to delete and withdrawn the item, change the policies, add/remove new bitstrems.

There is not a built-in support to give this permission to the submitter automatically, so you need to code your own consumer to do that (listen on the Install event) or you need to do that manually.

You can limit the functionality available to an ITEM admin in the configuration
https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace/config/dspace.cfg#L305

Moreover it could be better to look to the versioning system and allow the user to create new version of their items (only in the JSPUI 6.0), see
https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC6x/Item+Level+Versioning#ItemLevelVersioning-Allowingsubmitterstoversiontheiritems(JSPUIonly)

in this way if preserve past version that other could have used and cited